Does explain SELECT works only with found data?
In mysql 8 app I debug sql request by which index is in explain command and with sql :
explain   SELECT *
FROM `reactions`
WHERE `reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\Comment'     AND `reactions`.`model_id` = '30'
AND `reactions`.`action` = 4     AND `reactions`.`user_id` = 1

I have :
select_type = reactions_4fields_unique,reactions_user_id_foreign,reactions_model_type_model_id_index,reactions_4fields_index

where data found in db
If I use noneexisting user_id then
select_type = SIMPLE

for table with structure :
CREATE TABLE `reactions` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reactions_4fields_unique` (`model_type`,`model_id`,`user_id`,`action`),
  KEY `reactions_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `reactions_model_type_model_id_index` (`model_type`,`model_id`),
  KEY `reactions_4fields_index` (`model_type`,`model_id`,`action`,`created_at`),
  KEY `reactions_3fields_index` (`created_at`,`model_type`,`model_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reactions_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=222 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Does it mean that explain   SELECT works only with request, which founds some data ?

If you're testing an indexed column against a literal, the optimizer performs this test at the time that it makes the query plan. So the plan depends on how many rows satisfy the index, and if none of them match it can optimize away the entire query.

Not shure what 'against a literal" - that is behind my prior expierence. Could you please detailze or give a reference to relative docs?

WHERE `reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\Comment'` AND... is comparing with a literal string. Contrast that with a JOIN that compares a column with data in another table.
